# Angular mat-tab : content of only initial selected tab is loaded

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I am using mat-tab to display diagrams.

Each diagram is created with a query selector :

```
buildDiagram (stepName : string){

    let modeler = new Editor.default({
      container : document.querySelector('#diagram-'+stepName)
    });
```

In my component, I have a tab list :

```
steps = [
    {name: 'step1'},
    {name: 'step3'},
    {name: 'step2'}
  ];
```

For each tab, I create a diagram :

```
ngAfterViewInit():void {

for (let step of this.steps){
  this.flowsheetEditorService.buildDiagram(step.name) 
}
```

In my html, I'm trying to display the diagram of each tab like this :

```
<mat-tab-group 'class="diagramTabsContainer">

            <mat-tab *ngFor="let step of steps" [label] = "step.name">
    
                    <div [id]="'diagram-'+step.name" style='height: 74vh;'></div>
             
            </mat-tab>

  </mat-tab-group>
```

The problem is that only the diagram of the initial selected tab is displayed.

Can you help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would load the information on `selectedTabChange()` then load the information into the diagram. cause, indeed angular `mat-tab` are eagerly loaded, but :

> Eagerly loaded tabs will initalize the child components but **not inject them into the DOM** until the tab is activated - [Angular documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading)

An example

```html
    <mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index" [label] = "step.name">
         <div [id]="'diagram-'+step.name" style='height: 74vh;'></div>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

```js
steps = [
    {name: 'step1'},
    {name: 'step3'},
    {name: 'step2'}
  ];

 constructor() {}

 onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.buildDiagram(this.steps[event.index])
 }

buildDiagram (stepName : string){
    let modeler = new Editor.default({
      container : document.querySelector('#diagram-'+stepName)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution is to use Lazy-loading in your  and refactor the content in your mat-tab in a component and calling ngAfterViewInit in that component.
e.g.

```
<mat-tab label="First">
  <ng-template matTabContent>
    Content 1 - Loaded: {{getTimeLoaded(1) | date:'medium'}}
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

> If the tab contains several complex child components or the tab's contents rely on DOM calculations during initialization, it is advised to lazy load the tab's content. Tab contents can be lazy loaded by declaring the body in a ng-template with the matTabContent attribute.

[Angular Documentation - Tabs - lazyloading](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading)